# Mac Automator: Mass-create Subfolders

Tags: macos, automator, subdirectory

I am trying to use Automator to take a bunch of previously-created folders and create two new folders within each one, an "Originals" folder and a "Scans" folder. I would like to be able to drag or select the folders that need the subfolders and then have the action run automatically.

I've tried making both an action and a service to add the subfolders, but when I select multiple folders, it only runs once.

Here is a screenshot of what I've done so far...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the workflow as an Application:
[image]

Save the Application to your Desktop, then you can drop folders there whenever you want.

Here is an AppleScript that, when Exported as an Application, functions as a Droplet to make the desired folders in every folder dropped thereon:

```
on open droppings
    repeat with everyDrop in droppings
        if (info for everyDrop)'s folder is true then
            --make two folders
            tell application "Finder"
                make new folder at (everyDrop as text) with properties {name:"Originals"}
                make new folder at (everyDrop as text) with properties {name:"Scans"}
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end open

on run
    display dialog "Drop some folders here to add Originals and Scans folders" buttons {"Aye Aye"} default button "Aye Aye"
end run
```

Comment: I saved it as an application, but I still have the same issue. I dragged 3 empty test folders to the application, but the "Originals" and "Scans" folders were only created in 1 of the 3 folders...

Comment: That is crazy.  Your workflow looks sound.  I will experiment with it and see.  Have you made any changes to the workflow since your original post?

Comment: Infuriating.  I cannot make it work, either.  However, rather than spend my weekend figuring it out, I just put together an AppleScript that will do the job.  I hope it works for you.